# Apache POI SXSSF CreateSheet() Throws Java RuntimeException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
<ERROR>:<java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified>
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:568)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:584)
```

This was working perfectly till now. No changes made recently.

Can anyone help here please ?

Comment: Did you check the file permission?

Comment: Posting only an error message rarely helps.

Comment: Do you have write permissions to the temp directory? Did you remove anything from the temp directory whilst writing was in progress?

Comment: Thanks guys, Just now checked that the apache temp folder was removed. When i created the same, it started working.

Comment: Hello, Can you Please share Path Where you created this tmp folder for apache, I am having the same problem